# How to draw the slant operator for fractions using flex boxes?

Tags: webkit

I want to draw the slant operator for fractions. i e. bevelled operator on mfrac. How can draw that using flex boxes. For example: a/b instead of normal fraction. I want idea for implementation of the former one. that is for the type a/b using c++.